# How to make div expand with content using flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 214px;
  background: #eee;
}

.abbr {
  /* some styling */
}

.name {
  /* some styling */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name">Mark Smith</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if I use just `min-width`, the whole div stretches as the entire width of the container. If I just use `width`, it won't expand if the name is longer than `Mark Smith` (rather it will go to the next line).

This is what I wanted to achieve:

[image]

How do I achieve this in flexbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is to apply **[`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content)** to `.group`.

Then you can adjust the offset between the abbreviation and name with `min-width` on the `.abbr`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.group > div {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.abbr {
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name">Mark Smith</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name">A Really Really Long Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if I remove the `inline-flex` it still seems to work. Just need the `width: fit-content`.

Comment: Good spotting; I thought you needed both initially. I've updated my answer to correct this.

Comment: @catandmouse why not simply use `inline-flex` without setting width? it will work like this and better supported than fit-content

Answer (score 0):

I use `inline-block` on `.container` so that it won't take up the whole line.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
}

.abbr {
  padding: 0 7px;
}

.name {
  padding: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name">Mark Smith</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MR</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name">Loooooooooooooooong Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to use a third element that consume all the remaining space and set the background color on the text content only:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  
}

.abbr {
  padding: 0 7px;
  background: #eee;
}

.name {
  padding: 0 7px;
  background: #eee;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.blank-space{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <p>Mark Smith</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blank-space"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="abbr">
      <p>MR</p>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <p>Loooooooooooooooong Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blank-space"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```